# Oracle SQL. Error creating type

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm learning SQL.

When I try to create a type in Oracle SQL:

```
CREATE TYPE boolean_typ AS OBJECT
(valor char(5) CHECK (VALUE IN ('true', 'false', NULL)) );
/
```

I get this error:

```
Warning: Type created with compilation errors.
```

It gives no explanation on what is the error. May you help me?

Comment: `show errors` will tell you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type the following command right after you receive your error-message:

```
show errors
```

Show here:

```
SQL> CREATE TYPE boolean_typ AS OBJECT
  2  (valor char(5) CHECK (VALUE IN ('true', 'false', NULL)) );
  3  /

Warning: Type created with compilation errors.

SQL> show errors
Errors for TYPE BOOLEAN_TYP:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
2/16     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CHECK" when expecting one of
         the following:
         := ) , not null default external character

SQL> drop type boolean_typ;

Type dropped.

SQL> exit
```

Comment: Thank you. that is very useful. Still I don't understand what is wrong. I used the sintaxis shown here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp . It should work!